# History.js for jQuery fires unwanted "alert" in IE7

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-7, pushstate, history.js

I'm using History.js for jQuery in the following way (v1.7.1, html4+html5 bundle)

preparation at the the top of my js file:

```
(function(window,undefined){

    // Prepare
    var History = window.History; // Note: We are using a capital H instead of a lower h
    if ( !History.enabled ) {
         // History.js is disabled for this browser.
         // This is because we can optionally choose to support HTML4 browsers or not.
        return false;
    }

    // Bind to StateChange Event
    History.Adapter.bind(window,'statechange',function(){ // Note: We are using statechange instead of popstate
        var State = History.getState(); // Note: We are using History.getState() instead of event.state
        History.log(State.data, State.title, State.url);
    });

})(window);
```

then further down in my code:

```
    $foo.click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        History.pushState({}, "", "?" + bar);
    });
```

basically what I want to achieve is, every time certain items are clicked, the querystring `"?" + bar` is appended to the url and the pushState stores it in the browser history. This works perfectly fine in FF latest but when testing it in IE7, the following alert-like message appears:

[image: History.js error in IE7]
the url in the popup is the one I'm expecting, even though in the browser it appears as

```
http://www.foobar.com/.../#?Fixed
```

that is, with an extra hash. what worries me, though, is the error message - any clues?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for the records, if anyone happens on this page again - I've isolated the script and the error didn't happen anymore. After a long and tedious testing, I discovered that it was caused by a clash with a proprietary jquery plugin, and fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

Reason: You need to remove 'History.log()' from the code... In IE this History.log is writing the log output in alertbox...